# Extract images from damaged pdf

Tags: pdf

I have a pdf file that consists of a set of scanned images of a book. It is part of a series that is available [here](http://www.dhammadownload.com/Tipitaka-Pali-Myanmar(2010)-eBook.htm). Most of these work fine. The URL for the problematic file is [here](http://dhammadownload.com/File-Library/tipitaka/scanned-ebooks(2010)/04-1-TiPiTaKa-MuLaPanNarThaParLi(2010).pdf).

The file won't open and multiple command line tools fail to do anything with it. I have also tried a number of online pdf repair services to no avail.

I need to extract the images only. Normally I do this with pdfimages. I am not interested in repairing the file as such, unless of course it is essential for getting the images. Also, I know nothing about pdf code!

Here are some sample error messages:

Using `pdftocairo -pdf mn1.pdf mn1_repaired.pdf` and `pdfimages mn1.pdf` I get

```
Syntax Error: Invalid XRef entry
Syntax Error: Top-level pages object is wrong type (null)
Wrong page range given: the first page (1) can not be after the last page (0).
```

Using `pdftk mn1.pdf` I get:

```
Error: Unexpected Exception in open_reader()
Unhandled Java Exception in main():
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at gnu.gcj.runtime.NameFinder.lookup(libgcj.so.15)
   at java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace(libgcj.so.15)
   at java.lang.Throwable.stackTraceString(libgcj.so.15)
   at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(libgcj.so.15)
   at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(libgcj.so.15)
```

I'd appreciate it if someone could find a way to get the images out of this file. Solutions for Linux are preferred.

Comment: I tried `photorec` on the pdf, but it's more oriented to recovering from filesystems - it couldn't grab any images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uploaded the PDF to [this website](https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/repair.aspx) and it seems like it was able to successfully recover the file. It did, however, put a watermark on it, and it wants payment if you need a version without the watermark. All the text is still perfectly readable though, even with the watermark.

Here is the recovered file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sxubsn7rdy1olr3/pdf_recovered.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Ta, works fine, and when I extract the images with pdfimages there is no watermark.